Generating multiple OpenAPI examples when oneOf is being used with discriminator
In my response schema, I have some polymorphism.
Here is my base object.
PersonResourceAbstract:
  type: object
  properties:
    id: 
      description: blah
      type: string
  oneOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PersonResourceSummary'
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PersonResourceDetail'
  discriminator:
    propertyName: discriminatorView
    mapping:
      summary: '#/components/schemas/PersonResourceSummary'
      detail: '#/components/schemas/PersonResourceDetail' 

The summary and detail just have different levels of detail.  I was looking for a way where it was possible to see examples for both when PersonResourceAbstract is indicated as a return object for a request.
Doing this manually is a good bit of work, would love if docs generation just gave me this? like the way it gives you JSON with default values when you only use one object.
Any help appreciated.

which doc generation framework is used?

swagger ui is the generation tool @JeremyFiel

swagger-ui only parses what you give it. using examples as mentioned in the answer may work.

One shall use the examples propertie:
  /your-route:
    get:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/PersonResourceAbstractRequest'
      responses:
        '200':
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/PersonResourceAbstractResponse'                 
              examples: # here
                example1: 
                  summary: example1
                  value:
                    key: value
                example2: 
                    $ref: '#/components/examples/example2' #you might create it as a component

related answer
